# Apache file upload (resource PUT DELETE) without CGI/PHP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, rest, file-upload

Is it possible to configure Apache to support CRUD operations on file resources? GET works out of the box, how can you make PUT and DELETE work?

I would need to upload a file by HTML form and/or XMLHttpRequest2.
No PHP. No CGI. Just plain Apache by configuration.

Is this supported in other web servers? I'm trying to find a static REST interface for file resource management without CGI/PHP/Connector/Reverse Proxy/FTP server.